# NodeJS Express Routing - Serving Both Frontend and Backend on same NodeJS App

Tags: node.js, express, frontend, backend, express-router

I'm currently trying to wrap my head around the best way to achieve running my frontend and backend on the same NodeJS app.

I currently have two Express routers, one for my frontend and another for the backend.

Below is an extract of my UI/frontend route. On visiting `/` I want to redirect to `/dashboard`, I have a middleware that checks if you have accessed dashboard but not authed then you are re-directed to the `/login` route.

```js
const routes = (app) => {
    const ui = Router();

    ui.use(function (req, res, next) {
        console.log(req.originalUrl)
        if (req.originalUrl === '/login' || req.originalUrl === '/register') {
            console.log('public route hit')
            return next();
        }

        if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
            console.log('user is authed')
            return next();
        }
        console.log('re-directing to login')
        return res.redirect('/login');
    });

    ui.get('/', (req, res) => {
        res.redirect('/dashboard'); //If root is navigated to go to dashboard
    });

    ui.get('/dashboard', async (req, res) => {
        res.render('static/dashboard.html', {
            locals: {
                ...globalLocals,
                pageName: 'Dashboard'
            },
            partials: {
                ...globalPartials
            }
        });
    });
    app.use('/', ui);
};
```

An extract of my API routing is:

```js
const routes = (app) => {
    const api = Router();

    api.get('/logout', async (req, res, next) => {
        await req.logout();
        return handleResponse(res, 200, 'success');
    });

    app.use('/api/v1/', api);
};
```

The main issue I am having is that by having my frontend router path using `/` it then runs my authentication middleware on any API calls to `/api/v1/***`, which results in any login attempts on `/api/v1/login` result in a re-direction to `/login`.

How do I get around this issue? Should I have my frontend/UI routing on it's own path, such as `/app/` giving me `/app/dashboard`?

Comment: "best way to achieve running my frontend and backend on the same NodeJS app" -- front end doesn't run on Node, it runs in the client's browser. I'm not sure I understand your terminology.... can you clarify your intent, please?

Comment: Hi @ggorlen, sorry I should have made myself more clear in the opening post. I'm serving pages via Express with a templating engine, which are served using my `ui` router.